# How to scale down image when it's too big?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'd like to reduce the size of the photo when it exceeds e.g. 250kb, and keep the proportions. How to do this? Something like, I take a photo (5 MB) and I want to change size to 250kb before uploading on server. How to do it?

This is how I take camera picture.

```
  File imageFile;
    imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
```

Comment: use Image Compressor to compress image before uploading https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image picker](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/lib/image_picker.dart#L49) has a property  imageQuality. `assert(imageQuality == null || (imageQuality >= 0 && imageQuality <= 100));`

to set the quality/reduce size in % use

```
await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.camera, imageQuality: 50);
```